# How to extracting specific data from a JSON file?

Tags: python, json, deep-learning, dataset, export-to-csv

I want to extract only the text content from a json file. I tried to implement this topic, but I reached this step and I did not know how to extract the content only from the "text", and save the extracted data (text:content) in a csv file

```
import pandas as pd
import json
with open('shahd_yahia33.json','r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
df_nested_list = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path =['GraphImages'])
df = df_nested_list.iloc[:,16]
print(df)
```

the result will be something like this:

```
78                           [{'node': {'text': ''}}]
79                          [{'node': {'text': ''}}]
80                          [{'node': {'text': ''}}]
81                           [{'node': {'text': ''}}]
82                           [{'node': {'text': ''}}]
```

and This is a sample part of the data I am using:

```
{
    "GraphImages": [
        {
            "__typename": "GraphImage",
            "comments_disabled": false,
            "dimensions": {
                "height": 800,
                "width": 640
            },
            "display_url": "https://instagram.fnjf19-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/289451079_3011485445757272_2206549761362656362_n.webp?stp=dst-jpg_e35&_nc_ht=instagram.fnjf19-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=108&_nc_ohc=TjN-cA8G8NcAX9qBH1b&edm=APU89FABAAAA&ccb=7-5&ig_cache_key=Mjg2Njg4OTQ2NDQzMDkxNjI4NQ%3D%3D.2-ccb7-5&oh=00_AT_6mkMBSUhOLrS4KFzFa3J1UyTyr7HL6DiWVzcJ2roaXg&oe=62BBE498&_nc_sid=86f79a",
            "edge_media_preview_like": {
                "count": 1
            },
            "edge_media_to_caption": {
                "edges": [
                    {
                        "node": {
                            "text": "Good morning"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "edge_media_to_comment": {
                "count": 0
            },
            "gating_info": null,
            "id": "2866889464430916285",
            "is_video": false,
            "media_preview": "ACIqxt359e/X8ak2557VBEN/J6L+pPT/AOvU5NSMNopcCkXGRu+7nmrhQZyq5B7Dp+dAFOirxtl9cUUAZ0Qwn4/04qcBVDA/e798eg/qaZbON20DjqM9c/y9almGwMw6nFAxYF3/ACn5gaqhdpIBIGexNOEzkY4APXHH+c+1JxTJHbR6UUu8UUWGR2qkv7CpZyCdmcd8np9D/niordiFbBIqtISTzRYLlnaV4YY/z+tPGMcVBEx2kZOBRuPqaAJciiodx9TRTEf/2Q==",
            "owner": {
                "id": "27600881499"
            },
            "shortcode": "CfJPMdJtvK9",
            "taken_at_timestamp": 1655979877,
            "thumbnail_resources": [
                {
                    "config_height": 150,
                    "config_width": 150,
                    "src": "https://instagram.fnjf19-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/289451079_3011485445757272_2206549761362656362_n.webp?stp=c0.67.540.540a_dst-jpg_e35_s150x150&_nc_ht=instagram.fnjf19-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=108&_nc_ohc=TjN-cA8G8NcAX9qBH1b&edm=APU89FABAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AT-2oabihtpiNO5OZJHvUQnmGEiGquiytXOu4uouKZNBew&oe=62BBE498&_nc_sid=86f79a"
                },
                {
                    "config_height": 240,
                    "config_width": 240,
                    "src": "https://instagram.fnjf19-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/289451079_3011485445757272_2206549761362656362_n.webp?stp=c0.67.540.540a_dst-jpg_e35_s240x240&_nc_ht=instagram.fnjf19-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=108&_nc_ohc=TjN-cA8G8NcAX9qBH1b&edm=APU89FABAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AT8VQCOOH0lEIpPQrdd8LwfVzXN09XgNpSv9AG7Ko-91_g&oe=62BBE498&_nc_sid=86f79a"
                },
                {
                    "config_height": 320,
                    "config_width": 320,
                    "src": "https://instagram.fnjf19-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/289451079_3011485445757272_2206549761362656362_n.webp?stp=c0.67.540.540a_dst-jpg_e35_s320x320&_nc_ht=instagram.fnjf19-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=108&_nc_ohc=TjN-cA8G8NcAX9qBH1b&edm=APU89FABAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AT8eoYkONHDiSOiGOpi6TxMDW17pxuUWok3GPOHp81UKGA&oe=62BBE498&_nc_sid=86f79a"
                },
                {
                    "config_height": 480,
                    "config_width": 480,
                    "src": "https://instagram.fnjf19-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/289451079_3011485445757272_2206549761362656362_n.webp?stp=c0.67.540.540a_dst-jpg_e35_s480x480&_nc_ht=instagram.fnjf19-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=108&_nc_ohc=TjN-cA8G8NcAX9qBH1b&edm=APU89FABAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AT_fSMkXGf02tc7PyR4WytizjITO2n-qOoy_0ysk_KrppA&oe=62BBE498&_nc_sid=86f79a"
                },
                {
                    "config_height": 640,
                    "config_width": 640,
                    "src": "https://instagram.fnjf19-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/289451079_3011485445757272_2206549761362656362_n.webp?stp=c0.67.540.540a_dst-jpg_e35&_nc_ht=instagram.fnjf19-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=108&_nc_ohc=TjN-cA8G8NcAX9qBH1b&edm=APU89FABAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AT9I51ZVqmfC2wvCUTn_LffpnoDv6Ayvj4RR_KU8G_eXzQ&oe=62BBE498&_nc_sid=86f79a"
                }
            ],
            "thumbnail_src": "https://instagram.fnjf19-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/289451079_3011485445757272_2206549761362656362_n.webp?stp=c0.67.540.540a_dst-jpg_e35&_nc_ht=instagram.fnjf19-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=108&_nc_ohc=TjN-cA8G8NcAX9qBH1b&edm=APU89FABAAAA&ccb=7-5&ig_cache_key=Mjg2Njg4OTQ2NDQzMDkxNjI4NQ%3D%3D.2.c-ccb7-5&oh=00_AT9I51ZVqmfC2wvCUTn_LffpnoDv6Ayvj4RR_KU8G_eXzQ&oe=62BBE498&_nc_sid=86f79a",
            "urls": [
                "https://instagram.fnjf19-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/289451079_3011485445757272_2206549761362656362_n.webp?stp=dst-jpg_e35&_nc_ht=instagram.fnjf19-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=108&_nc_ohc=TjN-cA8G8NcAX9qBH1b&edm=APU89FABAAAA&ccb=7-5&ig_cache_key=Mjg2Njg4OTQ2NDQzMDkxNjI4NQ%3D%3D.2-ccb7-5&oh=00_AT_6mkMBSUhOLrS4KFzFa3J1UyTyr7HL6DiWVzcJ2roaXg&oe=62BBE498&_nc_sid=86f79a"
            ],
            "username": "shahd_yahia33"
        },
```

Comment: `extract the content` and `save in CSV file` are two separate, unrelated functions ... which one is giving you trouble?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract only the content from the 'text' key into a dataframe something like this would work:

```
def extract_values(entry):
    return entry[0]['node']['text']


with open('shahd_yahia33.json','r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
df_nested_list = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path =['GraphImages'])
df = df_nested_list.iloc[:,16]


df = df.apply(extract_values)
print(df)
```

After all of the preprocessing already completed in the posted code we use the `df.apply` operation to apply the extraction function to each `entry`. This gives us an output like the below with the sample file:

```
0    Good morning
Name: edge_media_to_caption.edges, dtype: object
```

Finally we can save to a csv using the `to_csv` operation:

```
df.to_csv("./extracted.csv")
```